# How to save the state of a KineticJS and restore it

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

What is the best way to save a KineticJs with all its Layers, Shapes and event function callbacks.

I have the following

```
var stage; //KinetiJS stage
var backgroundLayer //KineticJS Layer
var backgroundImage //KineticJS Image
var extraGroup; //A group to hold some extra shapes
var lineGroup; // A group to hold some KineticJS lines
```

I also catch the contentclick event on my stage

```
stage.on("contentClick", setContentClick);
```

On each click a point is drawn on stage using a Cirlce shape adeed on backgrounLayer

```
var point = Kinetic.Circle(...);
//some code here
point.on('mouseenter', function()...)
point.on("mouseleave", function()...);
point.on("dragend", function()...);
pointsAdded.append(point);
```

pointsAdded is a list of all points added so far on my backgroundLayer which is added on stage. My question is how or what is the best way for me to save the current state of the stage with all its children and callback functions and restore it. I want to be able to change between different states when user uses a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toJSON()` method to achieve this. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-save-stage-as-json-string-with-kineticjs/), in which you save the content of the Kinetic stage to JSON.

**Important:** However you should notice that events, function callbacks and images urls are not serializable. In other words, you will have to reassign all events, callbacks, etc, again after loading kinetic stage back from JSON in order to completely restore the previous state.